# Validation bug in Android

Tags: java, android, validation

I am making an app in which the user can send a message with the date he selects from a datePicker.

I made a register/login activities with validation and it worked without a hitch, so I tried to do the same with the message.
My code looks like this:

```
private EditText mEditMessageText;
private TextView mDateDisplay;
...
//    Validation
public boolean validate() {
    boolean valid = true;

    String message = mEditMessageText.getText().toString();
    String date = mDateDisplay.getText().toString();

    if (message.isEmpty() || time.length() < 5 || time.length() > 140) {
        mEditMessageText.setError("Enter between 5 and 140 characters");
        valid = false;
    } else {
        mEditMessageText.setError(null);
    }

    if (date.isEmpty() ) {
        mDateDisplay.setError("Set date");
        valid = false;
    } else {
        mDateDisplay.setError(null);
    }

    return valid;
}
```

Now I have the following problem - only the first error message is showing: *"Enter between 5 and 140 characters"*. I tried entering the text in the EditText field, without choosing the date from datePicker and I still got the same error message.

Could the TextView be the reason? Is there another way to validate TextView? Or could there be another problem?

Comment: Is `validate()` being called at the times that you expect it to? Try putting some logs in there to find out if it's just not being called.

Comment: @arjabbar It is. When i press sendMessage I get errors if the fields are empty. When I enter text and choose a date i can send the message.

Comment: There is a know bug in Jellybean 4.2 stated [here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=40417). You need to be focused on your second textView to get the setError Method working. Could this be your problem?. And also Make sure you enter more than 5 characters to test the second validation.

Comment: @Rengas I did enter more than 5 chars and I do believe the second textView is the problem. I will try to go through the link you posted tomorrow. TY